# Cappuccino [warn]: Could not connect the action

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

This has to be something stupid, because this is so basic and even then it is not working.

Anyways,

```
➜  ~  capp --version
cappuccino 0.9.6 (2012-11-17 788ee6)
```

I built a basic NibApplication from the template using the following command.

```
capp gen -t NibApplication ButtonTest
```

I did not symlink the framework.

I added the following method to AppController.j

```
- (IBAction)hello:(id)sender {
    alert("hello");
}
```

I ran XcodeCapp, opened the project in Xcode 4.5.2, and added a NSButton to the Window and linked it to the action "hello:" in AppController

When I ran the index-debug.html in Safari this is what I get in the console.

```
2012-11-18 22:58:01.566 Cappuccino [warn]: Could not connect the action hello: to target of class AppController
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In Cappuccino `(@action)` is a little more "proper" than `(IBAction)`, although both will work.

Answer (score 1):

So, I forgot to run it via a simple webserver. I tested it out by running it over Apache and it works. It's weird that the Safari console was not giving me any errors regarding this.

Comment: Unfortunately not even Safari does a good job with local pages anymore.